# Get client (requester) public ip at server behind NAT

Tags: ip, nat

I have searched without success a solution to my somewhat weird setup.
I have a standard home tplink modem-router that is connected to the internet (set up with static ip from the isp).
Inside the private network (let's say 192.168.x.x) I have a server (192.168.0.100) that runs a simple tcp server-side software listening on a specific port (let's say 12345).
I have set up port forwarding on the tplink to forward tcp port 12345 from any address to 192.168.0.100.
Everything works fine.

I want to be able to get the requester public IP address.
E.G. If a client (let's say public IP address of 202.67.85.112) is connecting to my server, and my modem static public IP address is let's say 50.60.66.77,  on the server I get 50.60.66.77 as the source address and not 202.67.85.112.

I understand that it is supposed to be like this, but is there any way that I can get the original IP address on my server?

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be like this. You should see 202.67.85.112 as the source address, not 50.60.66.77. A correctly setup port forwarding NAT will not touch the *source* address of packets coming from the outside - it doesn't need to. Two possible explanations: your router is doing something *very* weird and unusual, or you're misinterpreting what you're seeing.

Comment: Is it possible that the tplink replaces the ip?

Comment: Is the inbound address actually appearing as 50.60.66.77? Cause that's messed up. Etienne is correct, you shouldn't be having this problem. Port forwarding doesn't normally rewrite IP addresses. Definitely not a tplink router (not that I've ever seen). Though, it is possible to do inbound NAT... make sure you don't have something like that setup.

Comment: "Is it possible that the tplink replaces the ip?" > Technically yes, but that would be very strange. No correctly configured, sane router would do that. If your server is *actually* receiving connections from the outside where the source address is your own public IP address, it means something is very wrong with your setup. You might want to confirm what's going on using a sniffer such as Wireshark on your server's network interface.

Comment: Well, after checking again, restarting the router configuration and trying different setups, I finally got the client public IP address. Not exactly sure what was the problem but thanks to everyone that commented and made me realize that this situation is NOT normal.